# How to save changes when updating on Windows Form in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

```
List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
int id = 0;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Customer rec1 = new Customer("C0020", "Alfred", "Campbelltown", 1500, 2006);
    Customer rec2 = new Customer("C0021", "Ryder", "Liverpool", 2000, 2008);
    Customer rec3 = new Customer("C0022", "Alison", "Strathfield", 5500, 2012);
    Customer rec4 = new Customer("C0023", "Eliza", "Liverpool", 6000, 2012);
    Customer rec5 = new Customer("C0024", "Natsu", "Campbelltown", 2560, 2011);
    customers.Add(rec1);
    customers.Add(rec2);
    customers.Add(rec3);
    customers.Add(rec4);
    customers.Add(rec5);
}

private void NextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int length = customers.Count - 1;

    if (id == length)
    {
        id = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        ++id;
    }

    //Stage 3 Shows the total balance of all records and is displayed

    double total = 0;

    foreach (Customer Total in customers)
        total += Total.Balance; //Total Balance

    double balance = 0;

    foreach (Customer SubTotal in customers)
       balance = customers.Where(c => c.Suburb == "Liverpool").Sum( c => c.Balance);

    //Create a total balance for each suburb

    custID.Text = customers[id].ID.ToString();
    custName.Text = customers[id].Name.ToString();
    custSuburb.Text = customers[id].Suburb.ToString();
    custBal.Text = customers[id].Balance.ToString();
    custYear.Text = customers[id].Year_used.ToString();
    totBalance.Text = total.ToString();
    totSuburb.Text = balance.ToString();

}

private void PrevButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int length = customers.Count - 1;

    if (id == 0)
    {
        id = length;
    }
    else
    {
        --id;
    }

    custID.Text = customers[id].ID.ToString();
    custName.Text = customers[id].Name.ToString();
    custSuburb.Text = customers[id].Suburb.ToString();
    custBal.Text = customers[id].Balance.ToString();
    custYear.Text = customers[id].Year_used.ToString();

}

private void exitApp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}

private void updateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    customers[id].Name = custName.Text.ToString();
    customers[id].Suburb = custSuburb.Text.ToString();
    customers[id].Balance = double.Parse(custBal.Text);
    customers[id].Year_used = double.Parse(custYear.Text);
    this.Update(customers);
}
```

Im trying to save my changes with the update button but it doesn't seem to update when i try change a name or a balance and hit the update

Any ideas?

I have tried this.Update() function but did not work :( help would be appriciated

Comment: private void updateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    customers[id].Name = custName.Text.ToString();
    customers[id].Suburb = custSuburb.Text.ToString();
    customers[id].Balance = double.Parse(custBal.Text);
    customers[id].Year_used = double.Parse(custYear.Text);
    this.Update(customers);
}

Does not seem to work :'(

Comment: Where is your `Update` method?

Comment: so i have to create an update method for this? ahh this was my update button method

Comment: u called  this.Update(customers) method. wanna see that method

Comment: I assume your program won't compile, purely because there's no Update method that accepts an Enumerable. What does the compiler error say?

Comment: It runs perfectly fine but when i run the program i try and change a name of one of the persons on the list then when i click the update button and click on the previous button it comes back to the same name didnt update any changes to the form :(

Comment: Show us your Update method within your Form. `this.Update` calls a method in the Form, which it inherits from `Control`. However, this method takes no arguments and therefore your compiler will error if you haven't supplied your own override for `Update`.

Comment: this is my update form method
            customers[id].Name = custName.Text.ToString();
            customers[id].Suburb = custSuburb.Text.ToString();
            customers[id].Balance = double.Parse(custBal.Text);
            customers[id].Year_used = double.Parse(custYear.Text);

Comment: Am i calling the right function to use the update button by any chance?

Comment: In your `private void updateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` remove `this.Update(customers)`. Does removing that line work?

Comment: try to add a breakpoint within the 'updateButton_Click' method and debug then tell us what happened.